# Multiprocessing c in gtk c

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, multiprocessing

I built a code using multithreading and it works just fine as it is. When I click the button it start the loop writing in the console and when I click again it stops.

But, when I try to implement my real code there an error pops up: `error corrupted double linked list`.

I thinks it's because Thread are in the same memory space. I'm thinking about switching to process instead. Is there any library? Because all I can find are fork() and exec() and i'm not sure what I can do with them.

So how do I handle multiprocessing in a gtk application?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int CLICK;

void* fonc(void* arg){
 int i;
 while (CLICK==1){
    printf("nope \n");
    usleep(100000); //wait
 }
}

static void cb_clicked( GtkButton *button, gpointer   data )
{
 pthread_t interface, lancementWhile; //déclaration des deux tâches
    /* No need to call gdk_threads_enter/gdk_threads_leave,
       since gtk callbacks are executed withing main lock. */
     if (CLICK==0){
        CLICK=1;
        pthread_create(&lancementWhile, NULL, fonc, (void*)NULL);
        printf("you started \n");
        gtk_button_set_label( button, "Clicked" );

     }
     else{
        CLICK=0;
        printf("you stoped \n");
         gtk_button_set_label( button, "Unclicked" );
    }
}

void *creationInterface(void *arg){

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;


    /* Do stuff as usual */
    gtk_init( NULL, NULL );

    window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    g_signal_connect( G_OBJECT( window ), "destroy",
                      G_CALLBACK( gtk_main_quit ), NULL );

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label( "Initial value" );
    g_signal_connect( G_OBJECT( button ), "clicked",
                      G_CALLBACK( cb_clicked ), NULL );
    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER( window ), button );

    gtk_widget_show_all( window );

    gtk_main(); 
}

int main(void)

{
 /* Secure glib */
    if( ! g_thread_supported() )
        g_thread_init( NULL );

    /* Secure gtk */
    gdk_threads_init();

    /* Obtain gtk's global lock */
    gdk_threads_enter();


    CLICK=0;
    pthread_t interface; 
    pthread_create(&interface, NULL, creationInterface, NULL); 
    pthread_join(interface, NULL); 


}
```

Comment: Gtk functions should be called by the main thread only.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the thread does not seem to make any GTK+ calls...

Comment: @Asha that the code you posted works and your real code doesn't work doesn't help us fix your problem. Can you provide a code sample that produces the error you have?

Comment: Basile ==> Why ? Cause it does work, is there a reason i shouldn't do it this way ? Cause if I wan't an Interface that's not frozen during the While i don't see how else I can do....

Comment: @andlabs I can't really :(; the main part of the code inside the fonc() was build by someone else and i can't post it without her consent....But is it possible to make a script that does the same thing that this one with the pthread but with Process instead of a Thread ?

Comment: You should protect your list with a mutex

Answer (score 2):

gtk_main() should be call from main only and you should use flag to control threads.